# Lodash: Fail to filter by custom predicate consist of both match property and function

Tags: javascript, lodash

[lodash _.filter](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#filter) allows filtering by both match property and match function.

Given below data

```js
var users = [
  { 'user': 'barney', 'age': 36, 'active': true },
  { 'user': 'fred',   'age': 40, 'active': false }
];
```

By match property, I mean

```js
_.filter(users, { 'age': 36, 'active': true });
// => objects for ['barney']
```

By match function, I mean

```js
_.filter(users, function(o) { return !o.active; });
// => objects for ['fred']
```

I want to combine the 2 by converting match property into match function, as shown in `functionPredicate` function.

```js
const functionPredicate = values => {
  let funcPredicate = _.identity;
  Object.entries(values).forEach(([fieldName, fieldValue]) => {
    if (_.isFunction(fieldValue)) {
      funcPredicate = funcPredicate && fieldValue;
    } else {
      const newPredicate = item => item[fieldName] === fieldValue;
      funcPredicate = funcPredicate && newPredicate;
    }
  });
  return funcPredicate;
};
```

However, it does not work as expected ([playground link](https://repl.it/repls/WryJuicyInstitutes)).

```js
const _ = require('lodash');

var users = [
  { 'user': 'barney', 'age': 36, 'active': true },
  { 'user': 'fred',   'age': 40, 'active': false },
  { 'user': 'john',   'age': 40, 'active': false },
  { 'user': 'seth',   'age': 44, 'active': true },
];

const functionPredicate = values => {
  let funcPredicate = _.identity;
  Object.entries(values).forEach(([fieldName, fieldValue]) => {
    if (_.isFunction(fieldValue)) {
      funcPredicate = funcPredicate && fieldValue;
    } else {
      const newPredicate = item => (item[fieldName] === fieldValue);
      funcPredicate = funcPredicate && newPredicate;
    }
  });
  return funcPredicate;
};

const values = {'ageFp': user => user.age > 36, 'active': true}
const p = functionPredicate(values)
_.filter(users, p) // wrong, it gives me both barney and seth
// _.chain(users).filter({'active': true}).filter(user => user.age > 36).value() // correct, it gives me seth
```

However, if I remove `'active': true` from `values`, it does work, filtering out barney.

Can anyone help me understand why? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that `funcPredicate && newPredicate` doesn't combine the two predicates, it just returns the `newPredicate`, causing your predicates not to combine (see [&& operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Description)). Instead, you can create an array of all the predicates that must pass to keep an item in your array. Then for a given object, check if it satisfies all the predicates (using [`_.every()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#every)):

```
const functionPredicate = values => {
  const toCheck = [];
  Object.entries(values).forEach(([fieldName, fieldValue]) => {
    if (_.isFunction(fieldValue)) {
      toCheck.push(fieldValue);
    } else {
      const newPredicate = item => item[fieldName] === fieldValue;
      toCheck.push(newPredicate);
    }
  });
  return o => _.every(toCheck, fn => fn(o));
};
```

The above can be re-written using [`_.reduce()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#reduce) which allows you to iterate an objects keys and values as seen below:

```js
const users = [ { 'user': 'barney', 'age': 36, 'active': true }, { 'user': 'fred',   'age': 40, 'active': false }, { 'user': 'john',   'age': 40, 'active': false }, { 'user': 'seth',   'age': 44, 'active': true }, ];

const functionPredicate = values => o => 
  _(values).reduce((acc, fieldValue, fieldName) =>
    acc.concat(_.isFunction(fieldValue) ? fieldValue : item => item[fieldName] === fieldValue), 
  _([])).every(fn => fn(o));

const values = {'age': user => user.age > 36, active: true}
const p = functionPredicate(values)
console.log(_.filter(users, p));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```